# Google Chart horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, charts, webview, google-visualization

I'm trying to set the visualization of the graph to showing a maximum of 4 months with the possibility to scroll horizontally.

I have tried to set some property like hAxis, but the page retun me back an error "a.getTime is not a function" when I set it.

Another problem is that pick to zoom and horizontal scrolling only work in chrome desktop, but not in android webview.

```
    <html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages' : [ 'corechart', 'controls' ]
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


//RAW Data
var jsonString = '[[\"F1\",\"F2\",\"F3\"],[\"Gennaio\",10.0,11.0,22.0],[\"Febbraio\",5.0,15.0,20.0],[\"Marzo\",7.0,17.0,15.0],[\"Aprile\",7.0,17.0,15.0],[\"Maggio\",7.0,17.0,15.0],[\"Giugno\",7.0,17.0,15.0],[\"Luglio\",7.0,17.0,15.0],[\"Agosto\",7.0,17.0,15.0],[\"Settembre\",7.0,17.0,15.0],[\"Ottobre\",7.0,17.0,15.0]]';


// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart(){

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Months');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Consumption');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Consumption_2');
    data.addRows([
        [ new Date(2017, 0, 1), 3, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 1, 1), 4, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 2, 1), 5, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 3, 1), 6, 6 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 4, 1), 8, 7 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 5, 1), 3, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 6, 1), 4, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 7, 1), 5, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 8, 1), 6, 6 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 9, 1), 8, 7 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 10, 1), 3, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2017, 11, 1), 4, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2018, 0, 1), 5, 5 ],
        [ new Date(2018, 1, 1), 6, 6 ],
        [ new Date(2018, 2, 1), 8, 7 ]
    ]);

      //OPTIONS
      var options = {
          'title': 'prova assi tempo',
          isStacked: true,
          'explorer': {
            axis: 'horizontal'
          },
          'animation': {
            duration: 500,
            easing: 'in',
            startup:true
          }
          // 'vAxis': {
          //   'viewWindow': {max: 4}
          // }
          // 'hAxis': {
          //   viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
          //   viewWindow: {
          //     max: 4
          //   }
          // }
          // 'hAxis': {
          //   'viewWindow': {
          //     max: 3
          //   }
          // }
      };


      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);

}

</script>

<body>

    <div id="chart_div"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

values for `viewWindow.min` and `max` should have the same type as the values on the axis,
in this case `'date'` for the `hAxis`

e.g.

```
hAxis: {
  viewWindow: {
    min: new Date(2017, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2017, 3, 1)
  }
}
```

another option would be using a dashboard with a range filter (`ChartRangeFilter`)

see following working snippet,
here, set `range.start` and `end` on the filter...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Months');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Consumption');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Consumption_2');
  data.addRows([
    [ new Date(2017, 0, 1), 3, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 1, 1), 4, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 2, 1), 5, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 3, 1), 6, 6 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 4, 1), 8, 7 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 5, 1), 3, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 6, 1), 4, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 7, 1), 5, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 8, 1), 6, 6 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 9, 1), 8, 7 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 10, 1), 3, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2017, 11, 1), 4, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2018, 0, 1), 5, 5 ],
    [ new Date(2018, 1, 1), 6, 6 ],
    [ new Date(2018, 2, 1), 8, 7 ]
  ]);

  var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter-range',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartType: 'ComboChart',
        chartOptions: {
          chartArea: {
            width: '100%',
            left: 36,
            right: 18
          },
          height: 72,
          isStacked: true,
          seriesType: 'bars'
        }
      }
    },
    state: {
      range: {
        start: new Date(2017, 0, 1),
        end: new Date(2017, 3, 1)
      }
    }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart-column',
    options: {
      title: 'prova assi tempo',
      isStacked: true,
      explorer: {
        axis: 'horizontal'
      },
      legend: {
        alignment: 'end',
        position: 'top'
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'in',
        startup:true
      },
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 36,
        left: 36,
        right: 18,
        bottom: 36
      }
    }
  });

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
  dashboard.bind(rangeFilter, chart);
  dashboard.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart-column"></div>
  <div id="filter-range"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now the graph is filtered and scrollable, but inside the webview on android the scroll doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to solve this? This is my webview implementation.

 WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/google_chart.html"); // Can be used in this way too.

Comment: Yes, but we tried even to open the standard example at this
[link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) , but even this doesn't work on a mobile phone inside browser.

Comment: wish i could help, you can try adding an issue [here](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues)...