# Google Column Chart scaling/scrolling

Tags: charts, google-visualization, column-chart

Good day.
I have some kind of **Google Annotation chart**.

It looks like this:
[image]

I need to show values for few years by day.

Is it any way to make a **Google Column char**t with something like **scaling/scrolling** bar to display a lot of dates?

Unfortunately for the moment, it looks like:

[image]

And it seems really useless.

Comment: you can connect the chart to a `ChartRangeFilter`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48752228/5090771)...

Comment: Please try the 'upcoming' version, in which a lot of changes were made to improve axis ticks.